# Effect of +M and +R effect in basicity of 4-methoxy aniline

Tags: organic-chemistry

We know that methoxy group exerts a +M effect, as a result of which basicity should increase even after resonance as +M effect is considered to be stronger than resonance effect.
So by this reason 4-methoxy aniline must be more  basic than cyclohexane amine, but this is not true.
I am not able to understand what factor should make cyclohexane amine more basic than 4-methoxy aniline.

Comment: Cyclohexane amine is aliphatic whereas p-methoxy aniline is aromatic.

Comment: To get real insights you should compare 4-methoxy aniline with aniline.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned the $\mathrm +M$ effect, I'm assuming you're familiar with resonance and aromaticity.

This is a structure of cyclohexane amine:
[image]

Here, the lone pair of electrons present on the Nitrogen atom make it a Lewis Base (an electron donor).

This is a structure of 4-methoxy aniline:

[image]

Here the lone pair of Nitrogen is delocalized due to resonance. Hence it's not readily available for donation. That's why 4-methoxy aniline is a weaker base.

Comment: I would like to know the reason as to why this answer was downvoted. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, but isn't  resonance effect considered  to be less dominating than +M effect, in the second there's is a +M effect due to methoxy group, which should make it basic?

Comment: I think you should revise what $\mathrm+M$ and resonance mean, since it does not 'dominate over resonance' :). Due to resonance, the lone pair on Nitrogen isn't local to it, which means that even though there is a methoxy group, 4-methoxy aniline is still a weaker base than cyclohexane amine.